# Linq :varName.hits.select (x=>x.document).toList()

Tags: linq

I have the below codes :

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True().And(p => p["_latestversion"] == "1");
predicate = predicate.And(GetDefaultTemplatePredicatesExpression());
```

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
    predicate = predicate.And(GetPathPredicateExpression(path));
    var results = context.GetQueryable().Where(predicate).OrderByDescending(p=> p.Views).GetResults();
                if (results != null)
                {
                    if (results.Hits.Any())
                    {
                        return results.Hits.Select(x => x.Document).ToList();
                    }
                }

I am retrieving a list of records based on the latest version. But this code does not indicate the number of records to return back. Can I check whether does the above codes return whatever number of records that it retrieve from the database?

Comment: You can always ask the Count() method for number of returned rows. Otherwise I do not understand your question.

Comment: Well, firstly that isn't your *actual* code, as you've got the casing wrong. But assuming it succeeds, it will have as many elements as `varName.hits`. Of course, that may vary each time you iterate over `varName.hits`. Your question is pretty unclear - please be more specific.

Comment: Please refer to the codes above. I have edited to include more.

Comment: Your code (that isn't complete) will return a list of documents where each Document belongs to a Hit item. If you return a list of something, the number of item you will return is the numbre of item you have in your list. Is very hard to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me what that `GetResults()` call would be returning (is that an extension method you've defined? I can't find anything relevant as part of the .NET framework.), which makes it hard to make a firm statement about anything else.

I believe you can split the line:

```
var results = context.GetQueryable<ArticleItem>()
                 .Where(predicate)
                 .OrderByDescending(p=> p.Views)
                 .GetResults();
```

into three lines:

```
var query = context.GetQueryable<ArticleItem>()
                 .Where(predicate)
                 .OrderByDescending(p=> p.Views);
var count = query.Count();
var results = query.GetResults();
```

Which I  think will give you would you want.